# Реализация мини-бэкап программы C#

Tags: c#, резервное-копирование

**Задача:** реализовать мини программу по бекапу определенной директории определенного диска.

- Запускаем, программа делает первый бэкап и создает хеши всех файлов
- При повторном нажатии к примеру на кнопку backup it программа сверяет
  хеши или как-то так и копирует только те файлы которые изменились.

Думаю такое можно сделать на C#, но не понятно мне только о создании хешей и логике работы с ними, т.е как программа должна логически работать с хешами и определять что копировать, а что нет ?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.md5?view=netframework-4.8